# Issues in controlling audio url from control centre in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

I am playing audio from url in AVAudioPlayer. I am trying to control the audio from the control centre and from the lock screen. I am able to control seek and forward, backward functionality but i am unable to control Play/Pause functions from control centre.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter       sharedCommandCenter];


    [[remoteCommandCenter skipForwardCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(skipForward)];
    [[remoteCommandCenter togglePlayPauseCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(togglePlayPause)];
    [[remoteCommandCenter skipBackwardCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(skipBackward)];


    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *playingInfoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];

    NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    [songInfo setObject:@"your song" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:@"your artist" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [songInfo setObject:@"your album" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:@"0" forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime];
    [songInfo setObject:@"600" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];

    [playingInfoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
```